# Passing dynamic props to lazy loading components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement the lazy loading. So, after hitting one api, I am sending the promise object to the Class called Test.js. And in Test.js, inside react.lazy, I am resolving it. Now, after resolving the promise, I want to pass the response to my lazy loading component. But it only accepts class as a return type. Is there a way to pass the data of response to lazy component.

Code of Test.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react"
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native'
import LoadingIndicator from '../../generic_components/presentational/loading_indicator'
import { colors } from '../../../constants'

class Test extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { data } = this.props // data is a promise object
    const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve(data)).then(
        (response) => {          // I want to pass the content of response to Test2.js
          return import('./Test2')
        }
      );
    })
    return (
      <View>
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingIndicator color={colors.purple} />}>
          <LazyComponent
          />
        </Suspense>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Test
```

**EDIT: Solution**
So, as André Pint said, getter can do the required task.

So, in Test.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react"
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native'
import LoadingIndicator from '../../generic_components/presentational/loading_indicator'
import { colors } from '../../../constants'

class Test extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.response = {}
    this.getResponse = this.getResponse.bind(this)
  }

  getResponse () {
    return this.response
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.props // data is a promise object
    const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve(data)).then(
        (response) => {          // I want to pass the content of response to Test2.js
          this.response = response
          return import('./Test2')
        }
      );
    })
    return (
      <View>
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingIndicator color={colors.purple} />}>
          <LazyComponent
            getResponse={this.getResponse}
          />
        </Suspense>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Test
```

In Test2.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native'

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const data = this.props.getResponse()
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Test2
```

Comment: I think you need to call a method from Test2 and receive the data there. Importing this file means you are making its content available to Test instead.

Comment: Okay, using a getter function works. I am using class variable to save the response and then returning the same in getter. Thank you.